# Add animation (slower, smoother change) on Bokeh chart data changes

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

Is there a way (built-in or quick workaround) to make bokeh charts' data change more smoothly? I am streaming some data in a Bokeh dashboard, the data changes drastically from time to time, and I would like to allow a few seconds for the chart data to update (imagine a bar chart), like an animation ...

How can I achieve this? Any hint would be useful.

P.S. I am using Bokeh server and am already customizing my template (html, css, js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to animate things with Bokeh right now:

- Animate manually by changing the data slightly at short intervals. Pro: pretty easy to implement. Con: a lot of data churning, especially given that you're using a server
- Create custom glyphs that support such animation. Pros and cons are the opposite. You can check out [this example](https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/bokeh-image-format-standards-and-interoperability/4799/11?u=p-himik) to get an idea of how it might be done

Comment: Cool, it seems a lot of work to do per case. That'd be a good feature to add in order to help Bokeh stand out visually compared to visualization JS libraries.